# Coherence Exception in NamedCache.putall after updating coherence to 12.1.3

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, caching, oracle-coherence

I use coherence in my project with following configuration.
Everything is Ok with coherence 12.1.2, but after updating coherence to version 12.1.3, i have a problem. When i put for example 1000 item on cache one by one using NamedCache.put() there is no error, but when i put 1000 items on cache with calling NamedCache.putall once, coherence raises an exception.
My project is in java and is deployed on jboss.

**cache configuration:**

```
<distributed-scheme>
        <scheme-name>my-map</scheme-name>
        <service-name>MyMap</service-name>

        <serializer>
            <instance>
                <class-name>com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext</class-name>
                <init-params>
                    <init-param>
                        <param-type>String</param-type>
                        <param-value>pof-config.xml</param-value>
                    </init-param>
                </init-params>
            </instance>
        </serializer>

        <thread-count>100</thread-count>
        <local-storage>true</local-storage>

        <backup-count>0</backup-count>

        <backing-map-scheme>

            <read-write-backing-map-scheme>
                <internal-cache-scheme>
                    <ramjournal-scheme/>
                </internal-cache-scheme>

                <cachestore-scheme>
                    <class-scheme>
                        <class-name>myPackage.loader</class-name>
                    </class-scheme>
                </cachestore-scheme>
            </read-write-backing-map-scheme>

        </backing-map-scheme>
        <autostart>true</autostart>
    </distributed-scheme>
```

**Raised exception details:**

```
Exception in thread "pool-7-thread-1" com.tangosol.net.RequestIncompleteException: Partial failure
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.validatePartialResponse(PartitionedCache.CDB:56)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.putAll(PartitionedCache.CDB:123)
at com.oracle.common.collections.ConverterCollections$ConverterMap.putAll(ConverterCollections.java:1553)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$ViewMap.putAll(PartitionedCache.CDB:5)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache.putAll(SafeNamedCache.CDB:1)
at mypackage.CacheEnabledDataProvider.putOnCache(CacheEnabledDataProvider.java:66)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Portable(com.tangosol.util.WrapperException): (Wrapped: Failed request execution for myMap service on Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2014-10-20 18:00:25.737, Address=192.168.70.101:8088, MachineId=5642, Location=site:,machine:PS,process:9876,member:Mem_1, Role=CoherenceServer) (Wrapped: Failed to store keys="9112791815, 9165497418, 9199193873, 9192139970, 9392020128, ") Assertion failed:) Assertion failed:
    at com.tangosol.util.Base.ensureRuntimeException(Base.java:289)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.tagException(Grid.CDB:50)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache.onPartialCommit(PartitionedCache.CDB:7)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache.onPutAllRequest(PartitionedCache.CDB:85)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$PutAllRequest$PutJob.run(PartitionedCache.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$WrapperTask.run(DaemonPool.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$WrapperTask.run(DaemonPool.CDB:32)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$Daemon.onNotify(DaemonPool.CDB:65)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at <process boundary>
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.ThrowablePofSerializer.deserialize(ThrowablePofSerializer.java:57)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferReader.readAsObject(PofBufferReader.java:3316)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferReader.readObject(PofBufferReader.java:2604)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext.deserialize(ConfigurablePofContext.java:376)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.Service.readObject(Service.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.Message.readObject(Message.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.message.responseMessage.DistributedPartialResponse.read(DistributedPartialResponse.CDB:12)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$PartialValueResponse.read(PartitionedCache.CDB:4)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.deserializeMessage(Grid.CDB:20)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.onNotify(Grid.CDB:21)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.PartitionedService.onNotify(PartitionedService.CDB:3)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache.onNotify(PartitionedCache.CDB:3)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Portable(com.tangosol.util.AssertionException): Assertion failed:
    at com.tangosol.util.Base.azzertFailed(Base.java:209)
    at com.tangosol.util.Base.azzert(Base.java:166)
    at com.tangosol.net.cache.ReadWriteBackingMap$CacheStoreWrapper.storeAllInternal(ReadWriteBackingMap.java:5943)
    at com.tangosol.net.cache.ReadWriteBackingMap$StoreWrapper.storeAll(ReadWriteBackingMap.java:5067)
    at com.tangosol.net.cache.ReadWriteBackingMap.putAll(ReadWriteBackingMap.java:840)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$Storage.putAllPrimaryResource(PartitionedCache.CDB:7)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$Storage.postPutAll(PartitionedCache.CDB:27)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$Storage.putAll(PartitionedCache.CDB:14)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache.onPutAllRequest(PartitionedCache.CDB:62)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$PutAllRequest$PutJob.run(PartitionedCache.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$WrapperTask.run(DaemonPool.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$WrapperTask.run(DaemonPool.CDB:32)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.DaemonPool$Daemon.onNotify(DaemonPool.CDB:65)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at <process boundary>
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.ThrowablePofSerializer.deserialize(ThrowablePofSerializer.java:57)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferReader.readAsObject(PofBufferReader.java:3316)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferReader.readObject(PofBufferReader.java:2604)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.PortableException.readExternal(PortableException.java:150)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.ThrowablePofSerializer.deserialize(ThrowablePofSerializer.java:59)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferReader.readAsObject(PofBufferReader.java:3316)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferReader.readObject(PofBufferReader.java:2604)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext.deserialize(ConfigurablePofContext.java:376)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.Service.readObject(Service.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.Message.readObject(Message.CDB:1)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.message.responseMessage.DistributedPartialResponse.read(DistributedPartialResponse.CDB:12)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$PartialValueResponse.read(PartitionedCache.CDB:4)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.deserializeMessage(Grid.CDB:20)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.Grid.onNotify(Grid.CDB:21)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.PartitionedService.onNotify(PartitionedService.CDB:3)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache.onNotify(PartitionedCache.CDB:3)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.Daemon.run(Daemon.CDB:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if loader class defined in cachestore-scheme element, implements CacheStore instead of CacheLoader and leave store() and storeAll() empty, no exception is raised. According to oracle documents, implementing CacheStore is not necessary for read-only cache-store and implementing CacheLoader is sufficient. This might be a bug.
I am not sure implementing CacheStore with empty Store() and storeAll() methods when we need read-only cache-store has performance penalty or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would only implement CacheLoader (not CacheStore) if you are not writing back to the database.